# How to show a Message Dialog in GTK using GTK# (Mono)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, gtk

I would like to show a dialog inside my GTK# application (I'm using MonoDevelop).

Sorry for the silly question, but I'm pretty new to GTK and Linux in general.

Comment: Does [this link](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/dialogs/) helps you out?

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageDialog` class can be used to show a message. Example:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(window, DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Question, ButtonsType.YesNo, "Dialog text");
dialog.Run();
dialog.Destroy();
```

You can change the message type, buttons type and the text. The `window` is usually `this`, if the code is inside of the window class.